# Finding Updated Records from millions of Text Files

Tags: c#, database, hash, duplicates, comparison

We receive close to 100 text files accumulating to around 30 GB size  everyday. each file contains  several thousand records and each record spread across several lines. We parse these records and put them in a set of several related tables. Total records we receive each day goes above million.

As of today, we have no mechanism to find which  records we have already received earlier and which once are  new, so we parse all records, remove the old records and  insert new once in Database. This way we lose track of the updated records and have to reprocess all multimillion records every day.

I am looking for some mechanism which can help us efficiently compare the records from text file itself or once it is parsed and store in the database and tell us which records were updated and hence need to be replaced, which once are new and which once are duplicate and hence should be ignored.

Any help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

1. To clarify the issue further, on Record in text file gets converted to at least 6 tables, of which one is a master table containing the Primary key and rest of tables are child and can have more than one records.
2. Sometimes, the changes may be only in the Child table where a new record is added, so technically there is no change in all other tables,  but the Parent record needs to be considered as updated since one of its child table is updated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I must apologise about my English.

I recommend you to do the comparison on database because it will be more simple and fast. I assume that each file has a unique key [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key), if not it could be made but requires a cursor and the solution depends on the database you are using.

I've written the example in SQL Server, but the core is very similar in any database.

Suppose you have two tables:

- DB: is the table which contains old data
- FileImport: contains the content of the file

The tables are defined as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE DB
(KEY1   int,
 KEY2   int,
 DATA1  varchar(100),
 DATA2  varchar(100),
 Primary key (KEY1, KEY2))

CREATE TABLE FileImport
(KEY1   int,
 KEY2   int,
 DATA1  varchar(100),
 DATA2  varchar(100),
 Primary key (KEY1, KEY2))
```

Where Key1 and Key2 conform the unique key of the document, and Data1 and Data2 is the information.

The following query will do the work:

Select  case
when d.Key1 is null then 'New Record'
when f.Data1 = d.Data1 and f.Data2 = d.Data2 then 'Duplicate Record'
else 'Modified Record'
end,
f.*,
d.Data1 DB_DATA1,
d.Data2 DB_DATA2
from    FileImport f left join DB d on f.Key1 = d.Key1 and f.Key2 = d.Key2

Where:

- New Record: the record in the file that does not exists in the database
- Modified Record: the record exists in the database and the file, but some field of data differs
- Duplicate Record: the record exists in the database and in the file, and has the same information

For example with the following data:

```
Insert into DB Values (1,1,'Dog','Cat')
Insert into DB Values (1,2,'Dog','Cat')
Insert into DB Values (1,3,'Dog','Cat')
Insert into DB Values (1,5,'Dog', null)

Insert into FileImport Values (1,1,'Dog','Cat')
Insert into FileImport Values (1,2,'Dog','Dog')
Insert into FileImport Values (1,4,'Cat','Cat')
Insert into FileImport Values (1,5,'Dog', null)
```

The query returns:

```
                 KEY1        KEY2        DATA1      DATA2      DB_DATA1   DB_DATA2
---------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Duplicate Record 1           1           Dog        Cat        Dog        Cat
Modified Record  1           2           Dog        Dog        Dog        Cat
New Record       1           4           Cat        Cat        NULL       NULL
Modified Record  1           5           Dog        NULL       Dog        NULL
```

Comment: The only problem is, one record gets updated in multiple Tables having Parent, children relation between them. There is  one Table with approximately 30 Fields and then there are around 8 other tables  which may have around 10 records per parent each. I think if we have parse the records, put then in their respective tables and then compare where Parent may match,  but not one of the child, the entire  process will take a ton of time to finish each day.

Comment: From my personal experience, it's very difficult to do a program that performs near as good as databases handling data. So if performance is an issue, and the process of importing the data in the database is not so expensive (view bcp utility as an option to import data fast), this is the best option.

Comment: Regarding the problem that one file matches with serveral tables, I think the best solutions is to have a table in the database with the same structure of the files, and keep this table with last version of the records (or the key of the record and a hash as David R proposes in order to save space). So match process will be easy easier and fastest.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no one clean way to do this. You don't mention where in those records the changes could occur. If there are a number of fields and you want to find the record where just one field changed, that is going to be a lot of work.

But, there are techniques that could be used.

For example, one idea might be to build a table of existing records. This table has a key, a hash of the record contents (and an index on that hash with duplicates allowed), and the record contents. Then, hash each record coming in and do a search on the index to find if that hash exists. If it does, then compare the record contents to see if they match also. If it doesn't, you know quickly that this is a new or changed record. Add that to the table.

Yes, this duplicates the contents, but in a different form than the processed data. A typical trade off when looking for performance is to trade space for search time.